# that will be (the) result of

Tags: zero-article

> If you don't define a default or parameter-less Constructor for your class the C# compiler creates one for it. You're not going to see it, but it will be in the IL or Intermediate Language code *that will be result of the compilation.*

I saw this sentence in a programming teaching video, I'm wondering why there is no definite article before *result*, I've Googled around for use cases of zero article but find nothing related to this situation.

The video is [here](https://youtu.be/q7aWkjH3UUI?t=81)

Comment: If the video you are asking about is publicly accessible (for example on YouTube), please include in your question a link to it at the approximate time where the the line at issue starts.

Comment: @Eddie Kal♦ Link included.

Comment: Great. It is obvious this guy is not a native speaker. He is pretty fluent but understandably makes mistakes in his speech flow. See, that is why you need to show us your source.

Comment: Mosh Hamedani, the speaker, sounds like he's a native Farsi speaker, and while his English is quite good, it's not perfect.  Articles work somewhat differently in Farsi - in fact, they have no definite article.  This is a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s just a mistake. There should indeed be a definite article in this context.